# wkhtmltopdf --enable-smart-shrinking doesn't shrink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I am developing a rails application using PDFKit.
I need to shrink the output into one page.
So I passed --disable-smart-shrinking=>false. (I tried --enable-smart-shrinking=>true but it doesn't make difference)

```
  PDFKit.configure do |config|
    config.wkhtmltopdf = "/some/path/wkhtmltopdf"
    config.default_options = {
      :encoding=>"UTF-8",
      :page_size=>"Letter",
      :margin_top=>"0.25in",
      :margin_right=>"0.5in",
      :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
      :margin_left=>"0.5in",
      :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
    }
  end
```

Shrinking works on my dev machine(OS X) but doesn't on the production server (Linux).
Version 0.11.0 rc1 on the linux doesn't shrink.
Version 0.9.9 on my OS X shrinks.

Can you help me with it?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: For me, in linux it shrinks and in Mac OS high sierra it doesn't shrink. with v0.12.4 (with patched qt)

Answer (score 1):

Some options (including the one you mentioned) only work with a patched version of QT. http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html Unfortunately I don't know any more than that, but it should get you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm using the patched version but passing --disable-smart-shrinking has effect, it still shrinks it...